# How to prove that $(b,\lambda-a)^T$ is the general formula for the eigenvector of a $2\times2$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$
with eigenvalue $k$. Show that unless it is $0$, the vector $(b, k - a)^T$ is an eigenvector.

If $k$ is the only eigenvalue, then $b$, $c$ should both be $0$, and both $a, d = k$, so that $(b, k - a)^T = 0$, so that shouldn't be the case. Then there should be $2$ distinct eigenvalues. However, I can't find a way to prove that the vector is indeed a eigenvector. Since the first component is $b$, the eigenvalue should definitely be $k$. But then I have trouble with the $k - a$ part.

Answer (score 5):

The key observation is that the vector $(v,-u)^\top$ is orthogonal to the vector $(u,v)^\top$. If $k$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$, then the matrix $A-kI$ is singular, and so its rows are linearly dependent. What is the first row of $A-kI$? It is the vector $(a-k,b)^\top$. Any nonzero vector $\mathbf x$, then, satisfying $(A-kI)\mathbf x=0$ must be orthogonal to the rows of $A-kI$, and hence must be a scalar multiple of $(b,k-a)^\top$, as desired. Well, there is an exception: What if $(a-k,b)^\top = (0,0)^\top$? Then we need to go to the second row and use the vector $(k-d,c)^\top$.

When $k$ is a repeated eigenvalue, as you said, then $A=kI$ and every vector is an eigenvector. The criterion applies only to the case of an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $k$ is an eigen value corresponding to the eigen vector $\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}b\\k-a\end{bmatrix}$, then

\begin{align*}
A\mathbf{v}&=k\mathbf{v}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b\\k-a\end{bmatrix}&=k\begin{bmatrix}b\\k-a\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}bk\\cb+dk-ad\end{bmatrix}&=k\begin{bmatrix}b\\k-a\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
Since the two vectors are equal to each other, we get
$$cb+dk-ad=k^2-ak \implies \color{red}{k^2-(a+d)k+(ad-bc)=0}.$$
But this holds true because the last equation is the characteristic equation of the given matrix and eigen values are roots of this equation.

If $ad-bc=0$ (i.e. the determinant is $0$), then $k=0$ will also be a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that $k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ is equivalent to $\det(A-k\operatorname{Id})=0$, which means that$$(a-k)(d-k)-bc=0(\iff ad-ak-dk+k^2=bc).\tag1$$On the other and$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}b\\k-a\end{bmatrix}=k\begin{bmatrix}b\\k-a\end{bmatrix}\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}ab+bk-ba=bk\\cb-dk-da=k^2-ak.\end{array}\right.$$The first equality is trivial and the second on holds, by $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $k$ is an eigenvalue, we know that $$\det (A-kI)=0$$

That gives you $$k^2-k(a+d)+ad-bc=0$$

This is what you need for the second component of the eigenvector to work. It may look messy but works fine when you multiply your matrix by your eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Since $k$ is an eigenvalue, $\dim\ker\left(\left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
  a-k & b\\
  c & d-k
 \end{array}
\right]\right)>0$, thus $\det\left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
  a-k & b\\
  c & d-k
 \end{array}
\right]=0$, then $$(k-a)(k-d)-bc=0\iff \color{blue}{bc}=(k-a)(k-d),$$ and
$$\left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
  a & b\\
  c & d
 \end{array}
\right]\left[
 \begin{array}{c}
  b\\
  k-a
 \end{array}
\right]=\left[
 \begin{array}{c}
  bk\\
  \color{blue}{cb}+d(k-a)
 \end{array}
\right]=\left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
  bk\\
  (k-d+d)(k-a)
 \end{array}
\right]=k\left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
  b\\
  k-a
 \end{array}
\right].$$